# Entry stamp of Ireland - is "until" date inclusive?

Tags: airports, ireland, passport-stamps, visa-expiration

I entered Ireland on June 4. When passing through passport control I told the immigration officer that I will leave Ireland on August 1. He stamped on my passport which shows "permission to remain in Ireland until 1 August". Does this mean that I have to leave Ireland before August 1? (i.e. leaving on July 31)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to leave before the midnight of the 1st of August; that means you can stay all day 1st of August, but must clear any immigration formalities before midnight.

Comment: So that means I can take the afternoon flight on August 1?

Comment: What I am a little confused here is whether the midnight of August 1 is the beginning or the end of the day.

Comment: Don't overthink it. The visa is valid till the 1st of August; so it means - that once the date switches from the 1st, the visa is no longer valid.

Comment: @BrianYang the phrase is ambiguous but typically means the end of the day: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/how-should-midnight-on-be-interpreted

Comment: I prefer 23:59 or 00:01 myself. I have midnight anxiety too